# JavaScript - Which syntax's name is defining function with two => character?

Tags: javascript

I read docs and see the new syntax at the first line. I searched but i don't find the syntax's name. Thanks for the answer!

```
const split = separator => string => string.split(separator); // which syntax's name

const spaceSplit = split(" ");
spaceSplit("Peter Parker"); // ["Peter", "Parker"]
```